# How much does basecoat/clearcoat paint cost for an airline?

Tags: airbus-a320, weight, paint

Suppose an airline with 15-20 A320 wanted to change the paint for the entire fleet, how much would it cost approximately?

I need this for my thesis, but unfortunately, paint manufacturers I contacted (PPG, AkzoNobel, Mankiewicz) don't want to give any information, since I don't work for an airline.

I understand that for an Airbus airplane the basecoat most likely is 9008 or 9008B900D.
Paint color should be white.

Note: Basecoat/Clearcoats reduce overall paint system weight, since they require fewer paint layers.

Comment: What's your thesis on?

Comment: Different measures of fuel consumption reduction in airlines. For the final part I'm trying to make an estimation of the costs associated with the implementation of such measures for a specific airline and compare that to the expected fuel savings (and money)

Comment: So you're thinking a lighter coat of paint for the weight savings? Might be something there. Be interesting to see how low long it takes to recoup the cost of a paint job in fuel savings. My ratty 30+ year old paint job is being stripped & repainted this fall. I'm hoping the drag reduction from the not very smooth paint (stored outdoors since 1996) will gain me  a little speed.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13738/1379

Comment: Already answered: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13738/how-much-does-it-cost-to-give-an-airliner-a-fresh-coat-of-paint